# Android Bundle Nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, bundle

I have two fragments and I am trying to pass an integer between them. In the first one, in Fragment_1.java I have this in onCreate:

```
pontszam = 12;
Fragment fragment = new Fragment_2();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("pont", pontszam);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Then in the second fragment, in Fragment_2.java I have this in onCreate:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myInt = bundle.getInt("pont");
TextView pontjelzo = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pontszam_2);
pontjelzo.setText(Integer.toString(myInt));
```

But I get nullpointer exception on this line:

```
int myInt = bundle.getInt("pont");
```

What am I doing wrong?

And this is how I open my second fragment:

```
button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();

            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left).replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment_2());
            fragmentTransaction.commit ();


        }});
```

Comment: How do you open your second fragment?

Comment: With a button:
button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();

                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left).replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment_2());
                fragmentTransaction.commit ();


            }});

Comment: Please edit you question instead... Large code blocks are not really readable in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing your first `Fragment` with a **new** `Fragment_2` instead of the one which has a `Bundle`.
Declare your `Fragment_2`above `onCreate` (globally), instantiate it:

```
fragment = new Fragment_2();
```

And change your `replace` line:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
```

Comment: That was my problem. Thank you.